# How make secondary HTTP request based upon results of first

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I have two async requests I am trying to fulfill, the second based upon the results of the first. The way I am trying to do this is by:

1. Listen for success of first action: `actions.GetAllItems`
2. Select out from the store the relevant items based on ID: `this.store.select(selectors.getItemsById)`
3. Map over the returned IDs so I can make the second call for each item in the array of IDs returned by the first call
4. Put results in redux store, render to view.

The way I have now *does* successfully put it in my redux store. However since it's just vanilla `Array.map` it doesn't return an observable. Which means the observable isn't stored in `this.details$`, which means it does not render in my template with `{{ details$ | async | json }}`

#### How can I achieve this secondary XHR call based upon the results of the first?

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.store.dispatch(new actions.GetAllItems())

  this.details$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(actions.types.GetAllItemsSuccess),
    mergeMap(() => {
      return this.store.select(selectors.getItemsById); // filter to multiple items based on item ID
    }),
    map((items: models.IItemGeneralResponse[]) => {
      items.map(item => { // sync map does not seem like it belongs in rxjs
        this.store.dispatch(
          new actions.GetItemDetail(item.id)
        );
      });
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you share the the type of details$ observable? Is it Observable<IItemGeneralResponse>?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do ngrx effects stuff in your angular component. Use effects to handle side effects (calls to the backend/fetching data from local storage etc...) and make your component to watch for a piece of your state via a selector. Let's summarize like this -

1. Your component [or your guard or resolver] will just dispatch an action to the store.
2. If you set up a reducer for that action then your reducer will be called first otherwise it will go to step 3
3. In your effect, you are watching for the dispatched action. Your effect will make the first call and then from the response of the first call, it will make the second call and then it will update the state in your store [or piece of the state] which is being watched by your component by dispatching the respective actions to the store.

This is a typical workflow [It may vary as per the need of the app but the basic idea remains the same]. So keeping the basic idea lets modify your code like this -

**In your component**

```
sliceOfState$: Observable<any>; //change the type of observabe as per your app

  ngOnInit() {

    this.store.dispatch(new actions.GetAllItems())

    //this observable will be used to render your data on UI
    //you can use various rxjs operators to transform your data before shoing to UI
    this.sliceOfState$ = this.store.select(//your selector which gives you sliceOfState);
  }
```

**Now In your effect -**

```
@Effect()
  this.details$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(actions.types.GetAllItems),
    switchMap(() => {
      //here you call API which makes the call to backend which return allItems
      return this.yourServiceWhichGetAllItems.getAllItems();
    }),
    switchMap(allItems => {
      //now for each item you need to get its detail
      //so forkJoin all the observables which calls the backedn for each item
      const obs$ = allItems.map(item => this.yourServiceWhichGetDetails.getItemDetail(item));
      return forkJoin(obs$);
    })
    map(allItemsWithDetails => {
      //here you should call your action which will update the state in your store
      return new actions.SetAllItemsDetails(allItemsWithDetails);
    })    
  );
```

I have provided pseudo code which will give you an idea of how to achieve what you want to do. For more info, you can visit the official site of ngrx - https://ngrx.io/guide/effects